# How to solve "ValueError: ' xxx ' is not in list" when extracting data from multiple files?

Tags: python, list, valueerror

I need to extract data from the files in CSVfolder. Each file contain columns "time_elapsed", "x_pred_normalised", "y_pred_normalised"... This is a script written by other colleage. I don't know much about Python...

```
rawResultsFileList = listdir("CSVfolder")
for file in rawResultsFileList:

    if file != ".DS_Store": # not sure what this is

        rawResultsFile = open(f"uploadsCSV/{file}", "r", encoding = "utf8")
        rawResultsFile = rawResultsFile.readlines() 
  # extract time data
        for line in rawResultsFile:

            lineEdited = line.strip("\n").strip(" ") # remove white space and \n

            lineEdited = lineEdited.split(",") # create a list, where each "cell" is an item

            # determine relevant indices
            if line == rawResultsFile[0]:

                elapsedTimeIndex = lineEdited.index("time_elapsed")

                normalisedXIndex = lineEdited.index("x_pred_normalised")

                normalisedYIndex = lineEdited.index("y_pred_normalised")

                faceConfigIndex = lineEdited.index("face_conf")

                typeIndex = lineEdited.index("type") # used to determine when to record faceConfig
```

What are the possible reasons for this error to occur?

```
ValueError: 'time_elapsed' is not in list
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the headers in your csv include whitespaces after the comma.
*"time_elapsed, x_pred_normalised, y_pred_normalised, face_conf, type"*

Your colleage tried to account for this by using `strip(" ")`.
However this only removed whitespaces at the beginning and the end of the whole header line (not between the words).
To fix this use `replace()`

```py
lineEdited = line.strip("\n").replace(" ", "")  # removes ALL whitspaces and \n
```